# Making django-passwords and django-registration-redux work together without editing pip-installed libraries

Tags: django, authentication, django-models

I want to use `django-passwords` to enforce password complexity. I am also using `django-registration-redux` to manage user accounts.

`django-passwords` enforces complexity on instances of `passwords.fields.PasswordField`. However, `django-registration-redux` imports `django.contrib.auth` into `registration/users.py` via `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`, and hence password fields are managed by `django.contrib.auth`.

The problem is that `django/contrib/auth/forms.py` now manages user passwords, and these passwords are  read via

```
password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

I managed to fix this by changing the `CharField` to

```
password = passwords.fields.PasswordField(label=_("Password"),
                          widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

and hence successfully integrated `django-registration-redux` with `django-passwords`. However, now I am editing the Django standard library, which is not ideal.

How can I get around editing the standard library and make `django-registration-redux` work with `django-passwords`?

(I also tried to `exclude` the password from the model, and reimplement it, but it got awkward . . .)